# RabbitConnectionFactory not picking up properties file values

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

I create a simple Spring Cloud Stream project and added properties like:

```
spring.rabbitmq.host=127.0.0.1
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=homer
spring.rabbitmq.password=simpson
```

When I start the application, I see that rabbit connection factory is not using username and password from the `application.properties` file.

```
Created new connection: rabbitConnectionFactory#684cdc12:0/SimpleConnection@6418d920 [delegate=amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/, localPort= 65385]
```

Is there anything I am missing?

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you use deploy your application into the Cloud Foundry, then you should consider this option `spring.cloud.stream.overrideCloudConnectors`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Ditmars.SR2/reference/htmlsingle/#_configuration_options_3

Comment: Please provide more information; I don't think it's CF since he connected to `localhost` with user guest. I just tested it and it works fine for me...`2018-01-29 09:09:14.569  INFO 69078 --- [           main] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Created new connection: rabbitConnectionFactory#44a085e5:0/SimpleConnection@10a98392 [delegate=amqp://foo@10.0.0.3:5672/, localPort= 63821]`. Perhaps your properties file is not on the classpath?

Comment: I should have been more clear. I am not deploying to CF. I am running this locally in my local Rabbitmq. The user and password is created in admin plugin with permissions to default vhost.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue; which is strange. A dependency (AxonFramework) was upgraded (3.1.2) and I realized this started happening after that update. I rolled back to previous (3.1.1) version and the `spring.rabbitmq.username` and `spring.rabbitmq.password` was respected again. I'll create an issue on their repo.

Thanks for the responses.